# Jquery : Getting the attribute value

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to get the list of all attributes value of an element by using its id. My code is as follows:

```
<div id="DivRoles" align="center" style="">
<select id="newOptions" name="UserRole" multiple="multiple">
    <option selected="selected" value="1">Normal User</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="5">Senior Manager</option>
</select>
<!-----Need to get values from this list below------->
<div id="ms-UserRole" class="ms-container">

    <div class="ms-selection">
        <div id="currentroles" class="custom-header">Current Roles</div>
        <ul class="ms-list">
            <li class="ms-elem-selected" ms-value="1">Normal User</li><!--Need this value--->
            <li class="ms-elem-selected" ms-value="5">Senior Manager</li><!--Need this value--->
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<input type="button" class="input-rounded-submit" value="Save" onclick = "Javascript:UpdateRoles()"/></div>
```

Here I need to get the values of "Normal User" i.e. "1" and "Senior Manager" as "5". Then I need to concatenate the values and display the final answer as "15".

I m trying the below code but it dosent seem to be working:

```
function UpdateRoles() {
    alert("Hi");
    var list;

    $.each()('#ms-UserRole', function(){
        list += $.attr(".ms-selection ms-list li ms-elem-selected ms-value").val();
    });

    alert(list);
}
```

Please help me if any one knows the solution.
Thanks, NC

Comment: I have to ask, what is the purpose of getting the values and displaying them this way? Have you considered any potential problems if your list goes beyond 10 items? Then you won't know if "15" is a one and a five, or if it's a fifteen.

Comment: I need to pass this string for my ajax call and 0 I m not using

Comment: You might want to consider a different way of doing this, as you're still limiting yourself to 9 items. Once you get to double-digits, your code won't work. One fairly standard format of passing data between scripts is using [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Use_in_Ajax).

Comment: @Travesty3 : Yeah I am using that in my ajax calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var list = "";
$(".ms-elem-selected").each(function() { list += $(this).attr("ms-value"); });
```

---

If you want the numbers sorted, you should store them as an array first, sort the array, and then join it into a string:

**[SAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uXrHD/1/)**

```
var arr = [];
$(".ms-elem-selected").each(function() { arr.push($(this).attr("ms-value")); });
arr.sort();
list = arr.join("");
```

Comment: Thanks for this great solution ! I ve been trying since 2 hours ! Anyways its displaying the result as : " undefined513 " ?? why is undefined coming here?

Comment: I'm not sure...I tested my solution, and it seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/uXrHD/

Comment: Oh, I know what's wrong. Make sure you use `var list = "";`. Can't concatenate onto a null variable. Have to initialize it to an empty string.

Comment: Yeah its working exactly !! Now oly problem that I have is I need to sort that string in ascending order say 125 or 12357 not 72345 or 5123. I m getting the drop down dynamically and the order is not preserved.

Comment: Also jquery .sort() dosent seem to be working coz its a string and its mentioned here that it holds good for an array

Comment: @NealCaffrey: Take a look at my edit above. You should store it as an array, sort it, and then join it into a string. [Here is a sample](http://jsfiddle.net/uXrHD/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I quite understand but try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/PmHvU/1/)

```
function UpdateRoles() {
    var output = '';
    $('.ms-elem-selected').each(function() {
        output += $(this).attr('ms-value');
    })


    alert(output);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$('.ms-list').children().each(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('ms-value'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    var list = '';
    $('.ms-list').each(function(){
     //alert($(this).text());
    list += $(this).find('.ms-elem-selected').attr('ms-value');
   });

   alert(list);
```